# Авторизация в google с помощью OAuth 2 без использования браузера

Tags: java, google-api

Есть проект, на котором авторизация в сервисах гугл происходит через редирект ссылку, которую генерирует приложение и позволяет авторизовываться для дальнейшей работы с сервисами гугл. Есть ли у кого пример кода на java, как реализовать доступ к их сервисам без браузера. 
Нашел единственную ссылку, отвечающую на мой вопрос - http://open-thoughts.net/article/read/11 , но некоторые моменты там не прояснены по сему обращаюсь к Вам. В примерах кода для авторизации приведен пример только для .NET

UPD Сейчас я использую данный метод для авторизации

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // load client secrets
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(OAuth2Sample.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/client_secret.json")));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println("Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/ "
                    + "into oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("my@email.com");
    }
```

Но при выполнении все равно происходит редирект в браузер где отображается разрешение для приложения, как избавиться от браузера для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Это разве не то, что вам нужно? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview

Comment: Судя по всему то, но ясности от этого больше не стало, по сравнению с примером что указал выше ничего нового, к сожалнию, не увидел

Answer (score 1):

Первый раз, нужно руками получить данные через браузер. Потом тебе нужно из `credential` получить : `CLIENT_ID` , `CLIENT_SECRET`, `REFRESH_TOKEN`. Далее в заходим и все:

```
final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).build()
                    .setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);
            credential.refreshToken();
            return new Drive.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
```